# how to trigger hover on an element without actually hovering on it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I trigger hover effect of all the elements on a page without hovering on any element.

I've written this very basic code for example

```css
div
{
  background-color : red;
  height : 100px;
  width : 100px;
}

div:hover
{
  background-color : blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
</div>
```

Here the elements are red by default and turn blue on hover. What can I do so that the boxes are blue soon as the page loads without me actually hovering on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.focus()`

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
ele[0].focus();
```